# Netbook heats up too much

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, overheating

I have an old netbook (**Toshiba NB300**) which runs **Xubuntu 14.04**. The computer runs fine, but I'm facing an annoying problem with the temperature. It sometimes reaches **70 degrees** Celsius (according to the *sensors* command output) when I'm just doing some text editing in Leafpad. The fan starts running when I only have used the PC for a few minutes. I have tried several methods to reduce the temperature (Laptop mode, powersave governor, etc.), and also **tried Lubuntu**, with the **same result**.
Another fact is that I live in a place (the south of Spain) where the ambient temperature is quite hot (42 degrees!!). May that be the culprit of my hot computer, or is it another cause?

EDIT 4 AUGUST 2016: I made a little hack in Xorg to remove screen tearing, and I'm using Compton as my desktop compositor, instead of the Xfce default compositor. I put this new info as I'm in doubt if that could be the reason of the problem, but not sure...

Thanks in advice for your answers!

Comment: When you run `top` in a terminal window (or run another system monitoring tool), are there any  processes that are using a lot of CPU cycles?

Comment: I have run top and it seems that there are no processes that eat the CPU. It doesn't seem to be an issue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install TLP and Indicator-cpu, that should cool down your laptop.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw thermald indicator-cpu
sudo start tlp
```

Modify the battery so it is always in powersave.

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/ondemand
```

Find:

```
echo -n $GOVERNOR > $CPUFREQ
```

and replace `$GOVERNOR` with `powersave`

Reboot your machine.

```
sudo reboot
```

I also recommend you should install

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

and Preload, to reduce the RAM usage.

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

Comment: Ok, I have installed all the stuff above, and it seems to heat up a bit less, especially notable when not connected to AC. It does not reach 60 degrees when playing Youtube on Opera browser. However, I'm afraid about the microcode thing, I don't know if that can harm my processor.

Comment: The microcode updates are issued by Intel and will not harm your processor, just like an updated networking driver will not hurt your network card. That's not really a valid concern.

Answer (score 1):

As your netbook is at least 5 years old, you might consider changing a thermal paste on your CPU.

I've got nearly the same model - NB305 and had the same problem, the cpu was hot even when the system wasn't in high-load (no matter if it was Ubuntu or Windows7). Changing thermal paste saved me.

Comment: I'll do that as fast as I can, but I can't for now. Instead, I'm thinking about getting a cheap cooling pad, along with a lighter and smaller use of the netbook. However, I don't know if I could stay much time without changing the paste. There are many people around me with the same PC (the PCs were given by our governament 5 years ago) and the same problem, and their computers also run excellent (with both Xubuntu and Lubuntu (both 14.04 trusty), and also Android-x86 4.4 r1); they don't seem to be worried about the heating thing. Should they change their pastes as well?

Comment: I would suggest your friends to measure their temperature as well, I'm certain they all got at least 60-65 degrees in normal mode after 10 minutes of work. And it can be lowered down with changing paste.